# Adding number of lines with BufferedWriter/Reader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, lines, bufferedwriter

Please help me with adding number of lines of original file.

Im trying to write lines which met specified conditions from file A to file B. There is no problem, but I need to write number of lines of file A to the end of file B and also add number of lines of file B.

Program runs through file A, if condition is met, line is written to the file B, however I stuck to add number of lines after that.

For the last 2 hours I already tried second BufferedWriter, second "try" block, bw.write(lines) and many more, but nothing worked. System.out.println(lines) worked good, so Im really confused.

Here's my actual code:

```
try (
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fileA.txt"));
    BufferedWriter bWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("fileB.txt"));
    LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("fileA.txt"));
    ){
        lineNumberReader.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        int lines = lineNumberReader.getLineNumber();
        lineNumberReader.close();
        String line;
        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null){
            String[] values = line.split(" ");
            int time = Integer.parseInt(values[3]);
            if (time < 16){
                bWriter.write(values[0] + ' ' + values[1] + ' ' + values[2] + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `lines` what you want to add at the end of `fileB`?

Comment: Thats the main problem, I tried to put bWriter.write(lines) after the while cycle, then after "try" block, but nothing worked.. However when I tried System.out.println(lines) it worked, so I dont know, where is the problem

Comment: @PankajSinghal Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by adding `bWriter.write(""+lines);` after `while` loop.

You have to use `bWriter.write(string)` instead of `bWriter.write(int)`.

`bWriter.write(string)` - the `string` value is written to the file as is.

`bWriter.write(int);` - It won't work because the `int` passed is converted to corresponding `char` and is then written to the file. The `char` corresponding to your `lines` value must be some non-printable character, and hence you are not able to see it.

Comment: is it also possible to get number of lines that was actually copied to file B?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can put a counter variable inside the `while` loops `if` condition.